# dlopen function on android marshmallow's jni not working

Tags: android, java-native-interface

i have a code to delegate ffmpeg command line 
so in java code i put this

```
public class VideoManipulatorNative {
    static {
            System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg_caller");
        //System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg_caller");
    }
    public native String runCommand(String... args);
}
```

and in native library side i put this as code

```
#include "jni.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOG_TAG "TAGGG"
#define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)


int (*xmain)(int argc, char **argv);


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_mypackage_VideoManipulatorNative_runCommand
   (JNIEnv *e, jobject o , jobjectArray a){

void* lib=dlopen("./libffmpeg_c.so",RTLD_LOCAL);
if(!lib){
LOGI("LIB1 NULL");
}

lib=dlopen("./libffmpeg_c.so",RTLD_GLOBAL);
if(!lib){
LOGI("LIB5 NULL");
}

lib=dlopen("./libffmpeg_c.so",RTLD_LAZY);
if(!lib){
LOGI("LIB6 NULL");
}


lib=dlopen("./libffmpeg_c.so",RTLD_NOW);
if(!lib){
LOGI("LIB7 NULL");
}

xmain=dlsym(lib,"xmain");
if(!xmain){
  return (*e)->NewStringUTF(e,"XMAIN NULLL");
}
LOGI("STARTING");
int stringCount = (*e)->GetArrayLength(e,a);
int i = 0;
char *ar[stringCount];
LOGI("STARTING 2 %i ",stringCount);
    for (i; i<stringCount; i++) {
        jobject string = (*e)->GetObjectArrayElement(e, a, i);

        jstring estring = (jstring) string;
        char *rawString = (*e)->GetStringUTFChars(e, estring, 0);
    ar[i] = rawString;
        // Don't forget to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` when you're done.
    }
LOGI("STARTING MAIN");
xmain(stringCount, ar);
LOGI("STARTING 3");
//ffmpeg_cleanup(0);
    dlclose(lib);

  return (*e)->NewStringUTF(e,"test");

}
```

and the result is

LIB1 NULL
LIB5 NULL
LIB6 NULL
LIB7 NULL

that mean dlopen has failed to load the library 
but it is not happened on android lollipop and kitkat

anyone know why the library doesnt load on android marshmallow?

Comment: how to call [dlerror](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlerror)?

Comment: BTW what do you need `dlopen` for? cannot you just use your methods from those libs directly?

Comment: yes, i can call that method directly but in second call of main it crashed

Comment: i tried dlerror but dlerror gives me ./libffmpeg_c.so not found, why its not visible

Comment: ffmpeg works well on 1st time but on 2nd time it crashed

Comment: when i discovered it filtergraphs returns null on 2nd call, i m using ffmpeg-2.0.1

Comment: so `dlopen` will not help you: first you have to find out why it crashes

Comment: and did you run `ndk-stack`?

Comment: what is it ?    anyway ?

Comment: `ndk-stack` says filtergraphs is null ?

Comment: oh xmain=dlsym(lib,"xmain");

Comment: this program crashed on that line xmain=dlsym(lib,"xmain");

Comment: i tried ndk-stack and it gives me this ooutput 
Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xee9675d9
Stack frame #00 pc 00019788  
/home/hilman/Downloads/ffmpeg-2.0.1/android/build/jni/caller.c:26

which is poitning to xmain=dlsym(lib,"xmain");

Comment: so do not use `dlopen` stuff: use ffmpeg directly